# clear:both и IE11

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, internet-explorer

Создал `div` c `clear:both`, но правило не срабатывает в IE в целом.
Да и в разных браузерах старого образца тоже игнорирует данное правило.
Что это может быть?

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/css/clear

Comment: спасибо,в хтмлбук знаком

Comment: добавьте в вопрос минимальный html, который показывает проблему.

Comment: а как выглядит этот ваш clear ?

Comment: LenovoID, миновал проблему без использования clear. Спасибо